# babel transpilation returns object instead of string or function

Tags: reactjs, amd, babeljs, grunt-babel

My Component code looks like below.

```
    import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

export default class HeroBanner extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { columns, content } = this.props.data;

    return (
      <div className="conatainer-class">

      </div>
    );
  }
}

HeroBanner.propTypes = {
  content: PropTypes.object,
  columns: PropTypes.string,
};
```

And my .babelrc file is :

```
{
 "presets": ["react", "es2015","stage-0"],
 "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-amd"]
}
```

When transpilation is happening, its giving output as an "object" rather than a function or string.

This is output object.
Banner: Banner(props)
**esModule: true
__proto**: Object

This is causing React to throw an error:

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Transpiled Code :

```
    'use strict';

var _typeof = typeof Symbol === "function" && typeof Symbol.iterator === "symbol" ? function (obj) { return typeof obj; } : function (obj) { return obj && typeof Symbol === "function" && obj.constructor === Symbol ? "symbol" : typeof obj; };

define(['exports', 'react'], function (exports, _react) {
  Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
    value: true
  });

  var _react2 = _interopRequireDefault(_react);

  function _interopRequireDefault(obj) {
    return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : {
      default: obj
    };
  }

  function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) {
    if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) {
      throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function");
    }
  }

  var _createClass = function () {
    function defineProperties(target, props) {
      for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
        var descriptor = props[i];
        descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false;
        descriptor.configurable = true;
        if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true;
        Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor);
      }
    }

    return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) {
      if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps);
      if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps);
      return Constructor;
    };
  }();

  function _possibleConstructorReturn(self, call) {
    if (!self) {
      throw new ReferenceError("this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called");
    }

    return call && ((typeof call === 'undefined' ? 'undefined' : _typeof(call)) === "object" || typeof call === "function") ? call : self;
  }

  function _inherits(subClass, superClass) {
    if (typeof superClass !== "function" && superClass !== null) {
      throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function, not " + typeof superClass);
    }

    subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, {
      constructor: {
        value: subClass,
        enumerable: false,
        writable: true,
        configurable: true
      }
    });
    if (superClass) Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass) : subClass.__proto__ = superClass;
  }

  var HeroBanner = function (_Component) {
    _inherits(HeroBanner, _Component);

    function HeroBanner(props) {
      _classCallCheck(this, HeroBanner);

      var _this = _possibleConstructorReturn(this, Object.getPrototypeOf(HeroBanner).call(this, props));

      _this.createMarkup = _this.createMarkup.bind(_this);
      return _this;
    }

    _createClass(HeroBanner, [{
      key: 'createMarkup',
      value: function createMarkup(val) {
        return {
          __html: val
        };
      }
    }, {
      key: 'render',
      value: function render() {
        var _this2 = this;

        var _props$data = this.props.data;
        var columns = _props$data.columns;
        var content = _props$data.content;
        var containerClass = 'l-col-xs-' + columns.toString() + ' l-col-nopadding' + ' h-border-bottom';
        var storyCardClass = 'storycard storycard-' + content.text_position.toString();
        return _react2.default.createElement('div', {
          className: containerClass
        }, function () {
          if (content.headline_url) {
            return _react2.default.createElement('a', {
              className: storyCardClass,
              href: content.headline_url
            }, content.image && _react2.default.createElement('img', {
              className: 'storycard--image',
              src: content.image.image_path,
              alt: content.image.image_alt_text
            }), _react2.default.createElement('div', {
              className: 'storycard--text'
            }, content.headline && _react2.default.createElement('div', {
              className: 'storycard--headline',
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML: _this2.createMarkup(content.headline)
            }), content.subhead && _react2.default.createElement('div', {
              className: 'storycard--detail',
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML: _this2.createMarkup(content.subhead)
            })));
          }

          return _react2.default.createElement('div', {
            className: 'storycard storycard-<%= contents.text_position %>'
          });
        }());
      }
    }]);

    return HeroBanner;
  }(_react.Component);

  exports.default = HeroBanner;
  HeroBanner.propTypes = {
    content: _react.PropTypes.object,
    columns: _react.PropTypes.string
  };
});
```

Any help will be appreciated. Let me know if more details are required !!

Comment: What output is an object? What is your JSX? The error is JSX-related and you haven't included any of that in your example.

Comment: @loganfsmyth added most of the component code and complete transpiled code. When i looked deeper the problem is with `exports.default = HeroBanner` which is wrapping it in an object. If i just return HerBanner after editing transpiled code itself, it works fine.  FYI ... return HeroBanner Component is "object"

Comment: `exports.default` is expected. How are you importing it? If you're using `require` directly, then you need to do `.default`, but if you're using ES6 imports it should just work.

Comment: Can you share where you are *using* the component code?

Comment: @loganfsmyth yeah in my application, i am using requirejs. So as per your comment, i need to use .default or is ther any other way to make it look more elegant ?

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller I am using Component in a Backbone application using requirejs (i know this does make application architecture bit tricky but i have no other option.)

Comment: Is your application also run through Babel? If so, if you use an ES6 import in your app, does it work properly? Generally if you use ES6 module syntax, I'd recommend doing so everywhere. There is a Babel module to change this behavior, but it doesn't handle AMD, only CommonJS modules.

Comment: @loganfsmyth unfortunately my entire application doesn't run through babel transpilation. Thanks for your help !! I still feel .default might not have required with some option :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you

```
export default
```

something in an ES6 module, then in ES5 modules you'd need to access it via `.default`:

```
var HeroBanner = require("HeroBannerModule").default;
```

or similar, in RequireJS,

```
HeroBanner = HeroBanner.default
```

See [Misunderstanding ES6 Modules, Upgrading Babel, Tears, and a Solution](https://medium.com/@kentcdodds/misunderstanding-es6-modules-upgrading-babel-tears-and-a-solution-ad2d5ab93ce0) for more information, and see [the add-module-exports plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-add-module-exports) if you *really* want to get the old behavior back.